# reload page Already made in php

Tags: php, html

first Apologize because i dont know english very well.

i have php page for superuser of my site that has form in it . when superuser input the date in form and press submit , new information send to new page and show in the table the data that  input by other users . is there any way to refresh this new page by press refresh button?

At the moment when i press refresh , the content not change and not show new data enter by users.

```html
 <form  action="profilehesread1410.php" method="post">
   <fieldset class="m1410-info">
            <h4>لطفا تاریخ مورد نظر را در شش رقم بصورت yymmdd وارد نمایید </h4> 
   <input type="text" name="m1" placeholder="تاریخ در شش رقم">
   </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="account-action">
   <input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit"  value="بازیابی">
          </fieldset>
       </form>
```

2- code of profilehesread1410.php

```html
  <?php
$date=$_POST['m1'];
include 'db.php';
$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT branch,time,username,date,amount FROM hes WHERE date='$date' ORDER BY branch ");
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>
 <table>
         <button class="btn-chap" onclick="myfunction()"> چاپ</button> <br> <br>
 <script>
 function myfunction(){
  javascript:window.print();
 }
 </script>
<tr>
<th>ردیف </th>
<th>کد شعبه </th>
<th>تاریخ </th>
<th>ساعت </th>
<th>شماره پرسنلی  </th>
<th>مبلغ </th>
</tr>
<?php
$rownum=1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
   echo "<tr>\n ";
   echo "<td>";
   echo $rownum ;
   echo "</td>\n ";
   echo "<td>";
   echo  $row['branch']. str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5) ;
   echo "</td>\n ";
   echo "<td>";
   echo  $row['date'] .  str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5);
   echo "</td>\n ";
   echo "<td>";
   echo  $row['time'] .  str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5);
   echo "</td>\n ";
   echo "<td>";
   echo  $row['username'] .  str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5);
   echo "</td>\n ";
   echo "<td>";
   echo  number_format($row['amount']) .  str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5);
   echo "</td>\n ";
   echo " </tr>\n ";
   $rownum=$rownum+1;
 }
?> 
</table>
```

Comment: If there is no http redirect after the post, then a refresh should resubmit the form values and your data should be updated.

Comment: when user click submit, the page "profilehesread1410.php"  is load.

Comment: How are you refreshing/reloading the page?  Which browser and version?

Comment: firefox v 56.0 - it seems i have mistake some were .

Comment: How are you refreshing/reloading the page?